# CSS files, JavaScript files and images not rendering in production server

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

When I start my server in the production environment, my CSS files, Javascript files, and images are not showing up. I`m using Webrick for my production server and Rails 3.0.3.

Comment: Is your base URL different on production and development?

Comment: sorry pls i dont know the base url you are talking about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

in your *rails_app_path/config/environments/production.rb*.